# Post to multiple rows in mySQL from PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, post

I have researched numerous ways to handle this on Stack Overflow but I can not seem to get it to work. As a last result I am asking for help.

I am unable to post data to multiple rows.  I am able to post to 'id' to multiple tables, but for some reason I cannot post 'category' or 'tag' nor can I post any data to multiple rows.  And my server isn't producing anything in the error logs.  Can someone point out what I am missing or steer me in the right direction.  Thanks.

**/insert.php**

```
<?php

$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="database";
$server="localhost";

$name = $_POST['name'];

$category1 = $_POST['category1'];
$category2 = $_POST['category2'];
$category3 = $_POST['category3'];

$tag1 = $_POST['tag1'];
$tag2 = $_POST['tag2'];
$tag3 = $_POST['tag3'];


mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO tname (name) VALUES ('$name')";

mysql_query($query);

$query1 = "INSERT INTO category (name, category) VALUES ('$name','$category1'), ('$name','$category2'), ('$name','$category3')";

mysql_query($query1);

$query2 = "INSERT INTO tag (name, tag) VALUES ('$name','$tag1'), ('$name','$tag2'), ('$name','$tag3')";

mysql_query($query2);

mysql_close()

;?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the queries? Use `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` to see the error messages.

Comment: `table` is a reserved word in sql!!! See first query.

Comment: I am getting no errors, but nothing is showing up in the database except for $id.  I wish I were getting an error log.

Comment: jens - I used table for this question, it has a name in my database.  I will correct my question.

Comment: is your id column primary/unique? also agree with Jens, table is a reserved word.

Comment: mysql = deprecate and bad habit, PDO = good habit, mysqli = also good habit

Comment: when you are quering the database put it into variable and echo it afterwards like $somequery = mysql_query($query)

Comment: Did you turn on error reporting?
try to use `echo mysql_error();` after using mysql_query to get the latest error message.

Comment: I echo'd $query2 and received:
    INSERT INTO tag (name, tag) VALUES ('name','tag1'), ('name','tag2'), ('name','tag3') - with the correct values.  It is only posting the $name to the tables though, and only the first row.

Comment: running `echo mysql_error()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <?php

 $username="username";
 $password="password";
 $database="database";
 $server="localhost";

//connect
mysql_connect("$server", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$id = $_POST['id'];

 $category1 = $_POST['category1'];
$category2 = $_POST['category2'];
  $category3 = $_POST['category3'];

$tag1 = $_POST['tag1'];
$tag2 = $_POST['tag2'];
   $tag3 = $_POST['tag3'];

 echo"$category1";//if these are not getting printed you have error here
 echo"$category2";
echo"$category3";

echo"$tag1";
echo"$tag2";
echo"$tag3";



  $query = "INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES ('$id')";

  mysql_query($query);

 $query1 = "INSERT INTO category (id, category) VALUES ('$id','$category1'),     ('$id','$category2'), ('$id','$category3')";

 $result1=mysql_query($query1);


  // If successfully queried 
 if($result1){


  $query2 = "INSERT INTO tag (id, tag) VALUES ('$id','$tag1'), ('$id','$tag2'), ('$id','$tag3')";

  mysql_query($query2);

  }

  else
 {
 echo"error";
 }


  mysql_close();

   ?>
```

if you have problem in queries ,,, check table parameters

Comment: Everything prints, but then echo's error.  Still no error log.

Comment: so problem is at your query1,right?, are your table parameters correct? what are they set to?

Comment: Ok making progress. - it was a problem in the query.  BUT it still wont post to multiple rows.  I am getting the first row, but not the second or third.

Comment: you mean first query but not second and third queries or rows in first query?

Comment: the first rows of each query posts to the correct table, but the 2nd and 3rd rows of query2 and query3 arent being posted.

Comment: so In first query three rows completly posted right?

Comment: try query 3 with same if condition apllying to query2! as far as now your query statements are correct, there must be something wrong in  mysql table parametrs. keep on trying, remove foriegn spaces.,stop using mysql_query, start pdo,,small advice.

Comment: The error came from `Primary Keys` being set within the tables.  **Thanks for all of your help!**

NOW TO LEARN PDO

Comment: Accept or upvote my answer, if i was helpful to you...@joshclemence

Answer (score 0):

**Database:**

```
    SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";


    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
    /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

    --
    -- Database: `db_name`
    --
    -- CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db_name` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
    -- USE `db_name`;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `name`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `category`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
      `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
      `category` varchar(500) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Table structure for table `tag`
    --

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tag`;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
      `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
      `tag` varchar(500) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="insert.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Name">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="category1">Category1</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="category1" name="category1">
          <option value="categorya">CategoryA</option>
          <option value="categoryb">CategoryB</option>
          <option value="categoryc">CategoryC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="category2">Category2</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="category2" name="category2">
          <option value="categorya">CategoryA</option>
          <option value="categoryb">CategoryB</option>
          <option value="categoryc">CategoryC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="category3">Category3</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="category3" name="category3">
          <option value="categorya">CategoryA</option>
          <option value="categoryb">CategoryB</option>
          <option value="categoryc">CategoryC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="tag1">Tag1</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="tag1" name="tag1">
          <option value="taga">TagA</option>
          <option value="tagb">TagB</option>
          <option value="tagc">TagC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="tag2">Tag2</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="tag2" name="tag2">
          <option value="taga">TagA</option>
          <option value="tagb">TagB</option>
          <option value="tagc">TagC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="tag3">Tag3</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="tag3" name="tag3">
          <option value="taga">TagA</option>
          <option value="tagb">TagB</option>
          <option value="tagc">TagC</option>
        </select>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
    <?php

    $username="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="database";
    $server="localhost";


    mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $category1 = $_POST['category1'];
    $category2 = $_POST['category2'];
    $category3 = $_POST['category3'];

    $tag1 = $_POST['tag1'];
    $tag2 = $_POST['tag2'];
    $tag3 = $_POST['tag3'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (name) VALUES ('$name')";

    mysql_query($query);

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO category (name, category) VALUES ('$name','$category1'),('$name','$category2'),('$name','$category3')";

    mysql_query($query1);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO tag (name, tag) VALUES ('$name','$tag1'),('$name','$tag2'),('$name','$tag3')";

    mysql_query($query2);


    mysql_close()

    ;?>
```